# Python, ValueError, BroadCast Error with SKLearn Preproccesing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to run SKLearn Preprocessing standard scaler function and I receive the following error:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing as pre
scaler = pre.StandardScaler().fit(t_train)
t_train_scale = scaler.transform(t_train)
t_test_scale = scaler.transform(t_test)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-c0133b7e399b> in <module>()
      4 scaler = pre.StandardScaler().fit(t_train)
      5 t_train_scale = scaler.transform(t_train)

----> 6 t_test_scale = scaler.transform(t_test)

C:\Users\****\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.pyc in transform(self, X, y, copy)
    356         else:
    357             if self.with_mean:
--> 358                 X -= self.mean_
    359             if self.with_std:
    360                 X /= self.std_

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40000,59) (119,) (40000,59)
```

I understand the shapes do not match. The train and test data set are different lengths so how would I transform the data?

Answer (score 4):

please print the output from `t_train.shape[1]` and `t_test.shape[1]`

`StandardScaler` expects any two datasets to have the same number of columns. I suspect earlier pre-processing (dropping columns, adding dummy columns, etc) is the source of your problem. Whatever transformations you make to the `t_train` also need to be made to `t_test`.

The error is telling you the information that I'm asking for:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40000,59) (119,) (40000,59)`

I expect you'll find that `t_train.shape[1]` is `59` and `t_test.shape[1]` is `119`.
So you have `59` columns in your training dataset and `119` in your test dataset.

Did you remove any columns from the training set prior to attempting to use `StandardScaler`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "train and test data set are different lengths"?? How did you obtain your training data?

If your testing data have more features than your training data in order to efficiently reduce the dimensionality of your testing data you should know how your training data were formulated.For example using a dimensionality reduction technique (PCA,SVD etc.) or something like that. If that is the case you have to multiply each testing vector with the same matrix that was used to reduce the dimensionality of your training data.

Answer (score 0):

The time series was in the format with time as the columns and data in the rows. I did the following before the original posted code:

```
t_train.transpose()
t_test.transpose()
```

Just a reminder, I had to run the cell a 2x before the change 'stuck' for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

**t_train** shape is (x, 119), whereas **t_test** shape is (40000,59).
If you want to use same **scaler** object for transformation then your data should have same number of columns always. 
Since you fit **scaler** on **t_train**, that's the reason you are getting issue when you are trying to transform **t_test**.